# pyspark context issue: AttributeError: type object 'SparkContext' has no attribute '_jsc'?

Tags: python, pyspark

```
import os

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
import pyarrow

os.chdir(r'C:\2020\EYAIA\work\slack')
master_path = r'PRP.xlsx'
other_path = r'Book1.xlsx'
output = 'merged.xlsx'

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
master = pd.read_excel(master_path)
master.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

df = sqlContext.read.load('csvfile.csv', format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')
print(df)
```

Getting

> AttributeError: type object 'SparkContext' has no attribute '_jsc'

What could be the issue?

I am trying from pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create spark session object and then read data as:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('path/to/csv',header=True, inferSchema=True)
print(df.show())
```